# Class Cast Exception in adding FragmentPager adapter to ViewPager in Api 23

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-6.0-marshmallow, classcastexception, fragmentpageradapter

I Have an `Activity` class contains a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`
My Code work in device with api under 23 but not work in api 23
Actually strange Exception happens it said

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

I realize that `getItem()` method in `FargmentPagerAdapter` is not called in api 23.


And just for extra information I run my app on real device and not any emulator.

where is the problem?

My Activity Code:

```
public class ProductListActivity extends Master{
....
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    initMenu();
    initLayout();
    initSlideShow();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    categoryID = bundle.getString(CATEGORY_ID_INPUT);
    Log.i("ProductListActivity",categoryID + " ***");
    initList();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    G.currentActivity = this;
}
private void initList() {
    Cursor cursor = G.appDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ProductCategory WHERE FatherID = " + categoryID, null);
    List<ProductCategory> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    ProductCategory productCategory;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        productCategory = new ProductCategory();
        productCategory.ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")) +"";
        if((productCategory.ID + "").equals(  categoryID) )
            continue;
        productCategory.ExplainF = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ExplainF"));
        productCategory.FatherID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("FatherID")) +"";
        productCategory.ImgID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ImgID"));
        tempList.add(productCategory);
    }

    cursor.close();
    categoryList.addAll(tempList);
    adapter = new CategoryBrandPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),categoryList);

    productPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    categoryTabs.setupWithViewPager(productPager);
    Log.i("TestTest","LOGLOG6");

}


private void initLayout() {
    productPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.brand_product_pager);
    categoryTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_tabs);

}



}
```

My FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class CategoryBrandPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


List<ProductCategory> categoryList;
public CategoryBrandPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<ProductCategory> categoryList) {
    super(fm);
    this.categoryList = categoryList;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.i("TestTest","LOGLOG5");

    Fragment fragment  =new CategoryBrandFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString(CategoryBrandFragment.CATEGORY_ID_INPUT,categoryList.get(position).ID + "");
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return categoryList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return categoryList.get(position).ExplainF.trim();
   }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams 
 cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:203)

 at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.onMeasure(
 CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:410)

 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)

 at 

android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)

at 
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onMeasure(AppBarLayout.java:223)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)

at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(
CoordinatorLayout.java:714)

at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.
onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1042)

at android.support.design.widget.
AppBarLayout$Behavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:772)

at 
android.support.design.widget.
CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)

at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)

at  android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.
onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.
measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)

at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)

 at android.widget.LinearLayout.
measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)

at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6427)

at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)

at com.android.internal.policy.
PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3140)

at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2712)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1656)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1544)

 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7616)

at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)

 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)

  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)

  at android.view.Choreographer
  $FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)

   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$
  MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**EDIT:**

***Extra Information***

My Activity has a Master Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

 <ViewStub
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_bar_header"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:foregroundGravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    android:background="@color/menu_color_odd" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and `ViewStub` fill with below layout in `initMenu()`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/TabThemeDark">

    <include layout="@layout/app_header_second_type" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

         <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
          android:id="@+id/slider"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="180dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>




<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/category_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/mateForColorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/cardview_light_background" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/brand_product_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I remove or replace `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout,`CollapsingToolbarLayout` it works fine. it seems strange because my app still works under api 23.I have not seen any new changes related to this in android 6.

Comment: post your full stack trace.

Comment: Post your complete stack trace

Comment: post your complete code. post `initMenu();  initSlideShow();` method codes. It shows error in CollapsingToolbar, where you used that?

Comment: I debug my aplication there is no problem with `initMenu()` and `initSlideShow()` after thread exit `onCreate()` method  main thread in `Looper` class in `loop` method  stucks in a loop after hundreds of time executing the method  prints above stack trace. it seems the stack trace message is wrong and dose not represent the real problem and maybe just a problem from Exception Parser.